# What is a saying about motivation for work?

Tags: popular-refrains, phrase-requests

I'm trying to recall a saying I recently read. It was about motivation and went something like this: **"Don't complain about how complex something is, but wish you were smarter."**

Does someone know what the saying is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, thanks to my google search history!

> “Don’t wish it were easier. Wish you were better.” - Jim Rohn

Love that one.

Read more: http://www.keepinspiring.me/motivational-quotes-for-work/#ixzz3t0d2SieD

Comment: Ah, an antonym for "I'd rather be lucky than good"

Answer (score -1):

I can't be sure it's the same saying you're thinking of but your description reminds of something we used to say when people push on a door that is clearly labeled with the word "pull":

> You have to be smarter than the door.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't resist adding the iconic Far Side image for this.

Comment: No its been something different.

Comment: @blckbird oh well.  Can you offer any other hints?

Comment: I did a google search with something like 'motivation work' but I'm unable to find.

Comment: @blckbird is it in this [list](http://users.tinyonline.co.uk/gswithenbank/sayindex.htm)?